# Can getIntent be called in onCreate before calling super.onCreate in an activity?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-activity

I have a use case where I need to change the theme of the activity which is dependent on a value being accessed in intent. So can getIntent be accessed in onCreate before calling super.onCreate

Tried the above thing, works fine, but 1 device reported null intent extra value on an Android 8.1 device